# How do I change the marker edge color of a seaborn relplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to output a complex facet grid plot in the format of the following image:

[image]

But the problem is that I don't want the edge color of the markers to be white, I want it to be the face color.

In matplotlib, I can change the color of marker edges by calling the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({"values_x": np.random.randn(100), "values_y": np.random.randn(100)})

plt.scatter(x=df["values_x"], y=df["values_y"], edgecolors="red")
plt.show()
```

This produces a plot that looks like:

[image]

Now, if I call the following:

```
sns.relplot(data=df, x="values_x", y="values_y", edgecolors="red")
plt.show()
```

I still get white marker edges like in the following:

[image]

So, how do I correctly change the color of the marker edges within a call to sns.relplot()?

*For reference, I create the top facet grid plot with the following:

```
sns.relplot(data=df,
            x="C",
            y=metric,
            row="penalty",
            col="solver",
            hue="fold")
```

Comment: Remove $edgecolors="red"$ and it will give you the desired plot.

Comment: If I remove that I still get white edges around the markers. I want the edges to be whatever color I choose them to be. I actually figured out the problem and will update the question.

Comment: That's weird. I didn't get that white marks.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was with the parameter I was using. The parameter "edgecolors" is incorrect. The correct parameter is the non-plural "edgecolor". So the correct call to relplot is:

```
sns.relplot(data=df, x="values_x", y="values_y", edgecolor=None)
```

This would remove the marker edges completely, which is what I was trying to do originally.